# LIMIT and OFFSET in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query as below, 
 
I just added the last `line LIMIT ?, ?` because I'm trying to implement pagination. 
After adding last line I am receiving error `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '50''`

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Thanks!

```
    $offset = 0;
    $limit = 50;

    $get_products = "SELECT p.`product_id`, p.`product_name`
               GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(t2.`trait_name`,t1.`trait_name`)) name 
                       FROM `products` p 
                       JOIN 
                            `product_to_traits` pt1 
                         ON pt1.`product_id` = p.`product_id` 
                       JOIN 
                           `personality_traits` t1 
                         ON t1.`trait_id` = pt1.`trait_id` 
                       JOIN 
                           `product_to_traits` pt2 
                         ON pt2.`product_id` = pt1.`product_id` 
                       JOIN 
                           `personality_traits` t2 
                         ON t2.`trait_id` = pt2.`trait_id` 
                      WHERE 
                            t1.`trait_id` = ? 
                        AND t2.`trait_id` IN ($answers) 
                        AND `is_deleted` = 0
                   GROUP BY p.`product_id` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                      LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";

     $db = getConnection();
     $stmt = $db->prepare($get_products);
     $params = array_merge([$main_category], $answer, [$limit], [$offset]);
     $stmt->execute($params);
```

problem is probably somewhere in `$params = array_merge([$main_category], $answer, [$limit], [$offset]);`

beacuse in simpler query with variable:

```
  $get_products = "SELECT *
                     FROM 
                          `products`  
                    WHERE
                          `is_deleted` = '0'
                 ORDER BY RAND()
                    LIMIT :limit
                   OFFSET :offset";

            $db = getConnection();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($get_products);
            $stmt->bindValue('limit', (int)$limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue('offset', (int)$offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
```

everything works fine
So it is not a problem (like someone in one of the posts here said) that is impossible to put limit and offset in variable

Comment: you are using aggregate function count which should come after select ..For example SELECT MIN(age) FROM users WHERE condition ORDER BY DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ? . Here MIN is the aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to `order by count(*)` without having it in your `select`.